# Why is the blog link on the bottom going to a mobile version?

Tags: bug, blog

The blog link on the bottom sends me to a mobile version of the blog, while i'm not on a mobile device! :)

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/?blb=1

Thats it! :)

Comment: Looks fine to me, what browser are you using?

Comment: Reproduced in Chrome, Mac OS X.

Comment: Looks fine on Chrome Windows 7

Comment: No-Repro Chrome :  31.0.1650.63

Comment: Interestingly I don't get the mobile version even on mobile.  Presumably because you're stealing it for all your desktop views